# Sending concatenated fixed-length values with Python sockets

Tags: python, sockets, utf-8

I implemented a simple socket in Python, for sending integer values via UDP:

```
socket_client.sendto(str(value).encode('utf-8'), (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
```

Now I would like to send two different values with only one packet, concatenating as a 64 bit length payload.

Problem is that converted and encoded values have no fixed length so receiver cannot figure how to split the received payload...

My goal would be to send a 64 length payload as to be able to split in two different 32 bits integers... Is it possible?

Comment: It's spelled **length** - not "lenght" :...

Comment: `str(value).encode('utf8')` looks a lot like you are sending text, not numbers. Of course you can encode integers with ASCII digits, but `"0123"` isn't what I would call a 32-bit integer (even though it's UTF-8 encoding takes 32 bit). Can you clarify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Binary encoding

Python integers have a built-in `to_bytes` method, which conveniently serialises integers to `bytes` objects of a given length.
You have to specify the [byteorder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) and need to decide whether integers can be negative.

For example, this results in 32-bit big-endian unsigned representation (can represent 0..4294967295):

```
>>> x = 127
>>> b = x.to_bytes(4, 'big', signed=False)
>>> b
b'\x00\x00\x00\x7f'
```

You can simply concatenate two of those to get a 64-bit package.
NB: Send the `bytes` objects as such. Don't call `str(...).encode()` on them.

On the receiver side, you can use the `int.from_bytes` class method to parse a 4-byte string:

```
>>> int.from_bytes(b'\x00\x00\x00\x7f', 'big', signed=False)
127
```

#### Encoding with decimal digits

Your post isn't entirely clear.
Your snippet contains `str(value).encode('utf8')`, which could suggest that you intend to send numbers encoded with ASCII digits.
This is also possible – simply pad your numbers with zeros or spaces:

```
>>> '{:04d}'.format(127)
'0127'
>>> '{: 4d}'.format(127)
' 127'
```

On the receiver, parse the 4-byte strings with `int(...)`.
Note that this representation only allows for the range 0..9999.

Comment: Thank you, your binary encoding explanation was really what I was looking for!

Comment: Good to hear, @Kensou. You can "accept" this answer with the check mark so others will know it solved your problem.